# Set result in column as column name

Tags: json, postgresql, jsonb

I have this table:

```
-----------------------------
| cluster | nr | description|
-----------------------------
| A       | 1  | type       |
| A       | 2  | source     |
| A       | 3  | depth      |
| B       | 8  | rise       |
| B       | 12 | cause      |
-----------------------------
```

And I would like to create a json like this:

```
 { 
    "clusters": {
        "A": [{
               "nr": 1, 
               "description": "type"
           }, {
               "nr": 2, 
               "description": "source"
           }, {
               "nr": 3, 
               "description": "depth"
        }],
        "B": [{
               "nr": 8, 
               "description": "rise"
             }, {
               "nr": 12, 
               "description": "cause"
        }]
    }
 }
```

So thusfar I tried to do this:

```
select row_to_json(t)
from (
    SELECT cluster, nr, description
    FROM mytable
) t


select row_to_json(t)
from (
    select array_agg(d.cluster) as cluster
    from (
        SELECT cluster, surveynr, description
        FROM events.clusterbyactivescores 
    ) d
) t
```

and some other things I forgot..
none of which seems to do the trick.

What is the best way doing this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49742397/postgres-convert-single-table-in-grouped-json-tree

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `jsonb` type as it has [the `-` operator](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-json.html), which allows to build a compact and elegant query:

```
select jsonb_build_object('clusters', jsonb_object_agg(cluster, obj))
from (
    select 
        cluster, 
        jsonb_agg(to_jsonb(t) - 'cluster') as obj
    from my_table t
    group by 1
    ) s
```